# Virtualbox Mac OSX host - Ubuntu guest is slow and laggy

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, performance

I did some research already as to why my Ubuntu guest is slow on my (quite powerful) MBP but no success.

Is there something I am missing? A setting? A configuration?

FYI I am usin g: 
ICH9 chipset enabled
4096MB Base Memory
I/O APIC enabled
1 CPU
100% Exec cap
PAE/NX enabled
VT-x/AMD-V enabled
Nested Paging enabled
119MB Video Mem
1 Monitor
3d/2d disabled
SATA drive with AHCI Type.
Use Host I/O Cache: Disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that this is a known issue in Virtualbox, when you use a MBP RETINA and an external monitor, the performance is choppy/laggy.

I know use a headless VM through Vagrant/Puphpet. Works like a charm.